# Running Application Within PictureBox in VB

Tags: vb.net

For a smartphone simulation, my intention is to run applications on the `"screen"` of the smartphone, which is a picturebox. So far, I am using this code:

```
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class Form1
   <DllImport("user32.dll")> Public Shared Function SetParent(ByVal hwndChild As IntPtr, ByVal hwndNewParent As IntPtr) As Integer
    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim Process1 As New Process
        Process1.StartInfo.FileName = "Application_Name.exe"
        Process1.Start()

        Do Until Process1.WaitForInputIdle = True
            Application.DoEvents()
SetParent(Process1.MainWindowHandle, PictureBox1.Handle)

        Loop

    End Sub
End Class
```

However, this does not actually place the application over the picturebox (the application's form is positioned elsewhere). My intention is to have the application's form placed over the picturebox, and if it exceeds the size of the picturebox, to have scroll bars appear.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

In fact, the object in which the new application runs does not even have to be a picturebox so long as applications can run inside of it. Thank you.